# Remove whitespace after a symbol (hyphen) in R

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to remove the hyphen that divides a word from a string. For example, the word example: "for exam- ple this".

```
a <- "for exam- ple this"
```

How could I join them?

I have tried to remove the script using this command:

```
str_replace_all(a, "-", "")
```

But I got this back:

> "for exam ple this"

It does not return the word united. I have also tried this:
`str_replace_all(a, "- ", "")` but I get nothing.

Therefore I have thought of first removing the white spaces after a hyphen to get the following

> "for exm-ple this"

and then eliminating the hyphen.

Can you help me?

Comment: “I have also tried this: `str_replace_all(a, "- ", "")` but I get nothing.” — What’s “nothing at all”? What input did you use? Because that should work — it *does* work on the example input you gave.

Comment: The problem is that I have the text in a character vector and I do not know why I indicate that and it does not affect it. For that reason I want to remove all the spaces after a hyphen

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `sub` where we match the `-` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) and replace with `-`

```
sub("-\\s*", "-", a)
#[1] "for exam-ple this"
```

If it is to remove all spaces instead of a single one, then replace with `gsub`

```
gsub("-\\s*", "-", a)
```

Comment: The problem is that I have the text in a character vector and I do not know why I indicate that and it does not affect it. For that reason I want to remove all the spaces after a hyphen

Comment: @DavidPerea then just change the `sub` to `gsub` as `sub` does only for a single instance, while `gsub` is `global` substitution for one or more ..

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace_all(a, "- ", "-")
```

Comment: The problem is that I have the text in a character vector and I do not know why I indicate that and it does not affect it. For that reason I want to remove all the spaces after a hyphen

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to remove the whitespace after a symbol then Ricardo's answer is sufficient. If you want to remove an unknown amount of whitespace after a hyphen consider

```
str_replace_all(a, "- +", "-")
#[1] "for exam-ple this"
b <- "for exam-      ple this"
str_replace_all(b, "- +", "-")
#[1] "for exam-ple this"
```

EDIT --- Explaination

The `"+"` is something that tells r how to match a string and is part of the regular expressions. `"+"` specifically means to match the preceding character (or group/set) 1 or more times. You can find out more about regular expressions [here](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html).